# 'Page not found' when starting nodes

Tags: corda

I am trying to [test the example corda app](https://docs.corda.net/tutorial-cordapp.html#the-example-cordapp) from the official documentary:

I build my code successfully and now I started the nodes:

```
$ kotlin-source/build/nodes/runnodes
which: no osascript in (/c/Users/admin/bin:/mingw64/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/mingw64/bin:/usr/bin:/c/Users/admin/bin:/c/Program Files (x86)/Common Files/Oracle/Java/javapath:/c/Program Files/Microsoft MPI/Bin:/c/Program Files (x86)/NVIDIA Corporation/PhysX/Common:/c/ProgramData/Oracle/Java/javapath:/c/Program Files (x86)/Intel/iCLS Client:/c/Program Files/Intel/iCLS Client:/c/WINDOWS/system32:/c/WINDOWS:/c/WINDOWS/System32/Wbem:/c/WINDOWS/System32/WindowsPowerShell/v1.0:/c/Program Files/Intel/Intel(R) Management Engine Components/DAL:/c/Program Files/Intel/Intel(R) Management Engine Components/IPT:/c/Program Files (x86)/Intel/Intel(R) Management Engine Components/DAL:/c/Program Files (x86)/Intel/Intel(R) Management Engine Components/IPT:/c/Program Files/Lenovo/Bluetooth Software:/c/Program Files/Lenovo/Bluetooth Software/syswow64:/c/Program Files (x86)/MiKTeX 2.9/miktex/bin:/c/Program Files (x86)/Skype/Phone:/c/Program Files/Microsoft SQL Server/130/Tools/Binn:/c/Program Files/nodejs:/c/xampp/php:/c/ProgramData/ComposerSetup/bin:/c/Program Files/Geth:/c/Program Files (x86)/Windows Kits/10/Windows Performance Toolkit:/cmd:/c/Program Files/Microsoft VS Code/bin:/c/Users/admin/AppData/Roaming/npm:/c/Users/admin/AppData/Roaming/Composer/vendor/bin:/c/xampp/apache/bin:/usr/bin/vendor_perl:/usr/bin/core_perl)
Starting nodes in C:\Users\admin\Desktop\Coding Projects\learning_corda\kotlin-source\build\nodes
Starting corda.jar in C:\Users\admin\Desktop\Coding Projects\learning_corda\kotlin-source\build\nodes\Notary on debug port 5005
Starting corda.jar in C:\Users\admin\Desktop\Coding Projects\learning_corda\kotlin-source\build\nodes\PartyA on debug port 5006
Starting corda-webserver.jar in C:\Users\admin\Desktop\Coding Projects\learning_corda\kotlin-source\build\nodes\PartyA on debug port 5007
Starting corda.jar in C:\Users\admin\Desktop\Coding Projects\learning_corda\kotlin-source\build\nodes\PartyB on debug port 5008
Starting corda-webserver.jar in C:\Users\admin\Desktop\Coding Projects\learning_corda\kotlin-source\build\nodes\PartyB on debug port 5009
Starting corda.jar in C:\Users\admin\Desktop\Coding Projects\learning_corda\kotlin-source\build\nodes\PartyC on debug port 5010
Starting corda-webserver.jar in C:\Users\admin\Desktop\Coding Projects\learning_corda\kotlin-source\build\nodes\PartyC on debug port 5011
Started 7 processes
Finished starting nodes
```

Find below a picture how my started nodes look like:

[image]

When visitings `http://localhost:10010/web/example/` or `http://localhost:10010/api/status`, I get the following message `Page not found`:

[image]

Any suggestions what I am doing wrong?

I appreciate your replies!

Answer (score 1):

The images that you've put up show that the webserver has started on port 10009 for partyA. And your URL is on port 10010.I guess 10010 is for partyB who's node and webserver didn't start. Please check that you've all 7 java processes up and running. Which means 3 webserver and 4 nodes. Also check the logs in bulid > node>{party}>logs. The corda Webserver usually becomes available after the nodes have started up. Check the logs to see why one Node Party B  didn't start up  also what went wrong with webserver of Party B(won't start as party B Node didn't start) and Party C.

Comment: Yep - it says 7 Java processes, but the screenshot only shows 4.